# How to change encapsulation of 3rd party component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-elements, angular2viewencapsulation

I'm using AngularElements with native encapsulation so bs4 components can be used in bs3 project. Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-button',
  templateUrl: './my-button.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
  styles: ['@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";']
})
export class MyButtonComponent {}
```

The question is how to change encapsulation of 3rd party component so that global css doesn't affect it?
Given [NgbModalWindow](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-window.ts) component. How to change its encapsulation to ViewEncapsulation.Native and apply particular styles?

Here is [related issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1039)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a third party component inside a component whose `encapsulation` is set to native, global styles wont apply to that third party component.
E.g. If you use the third party component `ngb-modal-window` inside your own component lets say `app-my-own-component` whose encapsulation is set to native, the global styles wont apply to `ngb-modal-window` because it will be inside shadow root(of the parent `app-my-own-component`).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-own-component',
  template: '<ngb-modal-window></ngb-modal-window>',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
  styles: ['@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";']
})
```

However adding styles in `app-my-own-component` will get applied to `ngb-modal-window` in this case.

Another thing you can do is set `encapsulation` to `ViewEnacpsulation.Native` at global level so that all components in you application will have Native encapsulation. You can do this while bootstrapping your app module in main.ts file:

Change this:
`platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`
to this:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [
  {
      defaultEncapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
  }
])
```

You will have to import `ViewEncapsulation` inside main.ts of whatever the name of the file is where you are bootstrapping your module.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, NgbModalWindow is used not in my component but in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-stack.ts#L102
Even specifying defaultEncapsulation in main.ts doesn't change its encapsulation.